# .Net Settings file, complex types and serialization

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xml-serialization, settings.settings

I have the following types

```
[Serializable, XmlType(Namespace="http://mycompany/foo"]
public sealed class Limit
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Value1")]
    public double Value1 {get;set;}

    [XmlElement(ElementName="ComplexValue1")]
    public ComplexValue ComplexValue1 {get;set;}
}

[Serializable, XmlType(Namespace="http://mycompany/foo"]
public sealed class ComplexValue 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Item1")]
    public double Item1 {get;set;}

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Item2")]
    public double Item2 {get;set;}
}
```

which I want to serialize to a .settings file.

When I copy the blob below into the settings file, I lose the ComplexValue1 element somehow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Limit>
  <Value1>20</Value1>
  <ComplexValue1>
     <Item1>2.0</Item1>
     <Item2>5.0</Item2>
  </ComplexValue1>
</Limit>
```

i.e. Visual Studio transforms it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Limit>
<Value1>20</Value1>
</Limit>
```

with a bunch of namespaces that I think don't matter for the question...

What am I missing?

Comment: I kinda know the answer already, but come for points if you want :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need the `Serializable` attribute for XML serialization
2. I guess you should remove the `XmlType` attribute to solve the issue.
3. You specify a namespace but there are none in the XML file? This should fit too.
4. Use `XmlRoot` for the root node if you like

Comment: Those points do not solve the issue, indeed, the problem is the habit of VS injecting a "default" value inside the Settings.designer.cs file. But thanks for the recommendations anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Generating the code for the default value can be switched off on a per-setting base within the Setting designer. Just set GenerateDefaultValueInCode to false within the property window for those settings that don't need it.